# How to query cardano graphql api to get all assets metadata from a specific policy id

Tags: cardano-graphql

currently I'm using blockfrost to request NFT metadata information one by one from a specific policy_id. A policy ID can have up to 10k assets minted so it takes quite a while to fully sync to my local database.

Can I define a graphql schema to do the same thing with dbsync but with just 1 or a few request to the Cardano graphql server?

Was trying on https://graphql-api.mainnet.dandelion.link/ and couldn't figure this out, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while for me to figure out as well but this works. It will return all the asset ids of a particular policy

```
query TokensByPolicy($policy_id: Hash28Hex) {
  assets(where: { policyId: { _eq: $policy_id } }) {
    assetId
    policyId
    assetName
  }
}
```

And you need to pass the policy id as a parameter

```
{"policy_id": "7be8b5c60e913079bc1ccf58247dbaf5433fcb70d0abc89a7dd333d4"}
```

You can try it out at https://graphql-api.mainnet.dandelion.link/

[image]